# [SPTPlaylistSnapshot createRequestForAddingTracks not adding any tracks to the playlist or throwing any error

Tags: spotify

`SPTPlaylistSnapshot createRequestForAddingTracks` is not adding any tracks to the playlist, and not throwing an error. I am using the following piece of code:

```
[SPTPlaylistSnapshot createRequestForAddingTracks:partialTrack toPlaylist: [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",varArray.uri]] withAccessToken:[SPTAuth defaultInstance].session.accessToken error:&err];
```

The `partialTrack` variable is the array of `SPPartialTrack` Objects.

> ": Against All Odds
>   (spotify:track:0P1gmN35r2OnPy59kgspnZ)", ": Against All Odds
>   (spotify:track:728IDIbilgfPEr6KKFBDhX)", ": Against All Odds
>   (spotify:track:42uYe00QcC7hvXa85Clckm)", ": Against All Odds
>   (spotify:track:1ZIXm4irSIl43tjLSxxMFh)", ": Against All Odds
>   (spotify:track:2QBc7eCEKHByE39PSZtzNK)", ": Against All Odds
>   (spotify:track:6w19M2PM5nSJJ1G7KgRSL5)"

Is there anyone who has faced a similar problem?

Comment: I presume from the ObjectiveC syntax that this is using the iOS SDK?

Comment: Yes this is Spotify IOS SDK . As per the Spotify documentation, we just need to pass the array of tracks i.e SPPartialTrack  objects then it should work but its not working.

Comment: @ArvindSinghRawat I recommend you to post the issue on the [iOS SDK project's GitHub repo](https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk/issues) where you might help better support for this.

Comment: Thanks @JoséM.Pérez . Have posted there now